# Почему происходит редирект на другой маршрут laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, controller, route

У меня есть роуты "create" и "show". При нажатии на ссылку должно вести на "create", но почему то ведет на "show".

Вот роуты(Более полные в скрине):

```
 Route::prefix('projects')->name('projects.')->group(function () {

        Route::get('/', [Projects::class, 'index'])->name('index');
        Route::get('/{id}', [Projects::class, 'show'])->name('show');

        Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function() {

            Route::get('/create',  [Projects::class, 'create'])->name('create');
            Route::post('/upload', [Projects::class, 'upload'])->name('upload');
    
        });    
        
 });
```

Вот функции в контроллере

```
public function create() {
  return view('projects.create');   
}

public function show($id) {
  dd($id);
  return view('projects.show'); 
}
```

И вот ссылка

```
<a href="{{ route('projects.create') }}"> Добавить проект</a>
```

[image: Роуты]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что паттерн проверки урла маршрута подходит под оба случая и берётся тот, который определён первым

'/{id}' и '/create' это одно и то же. Маршруты example.com/1, example.com/hello, example.com/create, example.com/dfhjsdfjhsjfhsdhjfsjdh это всё /{id} а так как в коде данное определение маршрута стоит выше чем /create, то переходит туда.

Перенесите /create перед /{id} и всё заработает